# Upgrade Ubuntu Version 20.04 to 22.04

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, 22.04, do-release-upgrade

If I upgrade my system from ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04. Do I need to back up my data when I upgrade my system?

Comment: You *should* have backups of everything that's important to you regardless of what you do or don't with release upgrades. That said, the release upgrades are designed to keep everything personal intact, your personal files and as much as doable your user settings.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Always backup when doing anything as invasive as an OS upgrade. Always.

Though of course you should *always* have a backup anyway. But if you're not keeping regular backups, this is a good opportunity to change those habits!

Answer (score 1):

Upgrades aren't yet open; so if you perform the *release-upgrade* now without waiting (until after 4-August-2022) you're doing a *development* grade upgrade (ie. you're performing a test upgrade for Quality Assurance purposes to report problems for end-users for when the upgrade path *officially* opens).

[Ubuntu 22.04 release announcements](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/04/21/ubuntu-22-04-lts-jammy-jellyfish-released/) included this text

> Users of 20.04 LTS will be offered the automatic upgrade when 22.04.1
> LTS is released, which is scheduled for the 4th of August

so you'd be performing an *unsupported* upgrade at present, yet ask about backups?

Even if you do wait for the upgrade path to be deemed *ready* and fit for end-users to upgrade; you still of course should perform upgrades as already stated.

Any data you don't routinely backup is data that isn't important to you.